# XCode8 Swift3 - Problems with open contact list and retrieve data by click

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, cncontact, cncontactviewcontroller

Currently I'm developing my first iOS App and I'm a little slow and rude about the code (it's so weird and different from java) and, if this was the only problem, with the new update, Xcode is making my code insane. I think I solved most of the issues but...

Before, on one of the screens, the app opened a the address book and let the user click on one; when the clicked was done, the contact list close and data from that contact was retrieved to the controller. Now, if the user click on a contact, more info is displayed but any information come out of the console log.

I try everything I find on net and I'm not sure why is not working.

Before, I use `Addressbook` (or something like that) but I already tried with `CNContact`.

## This is the Button code

```
@IBAction func addNewContactOnClick(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        let peoplePicker = CNContactPickerViewController()

        peoplePicker.delegate = self

        self.present(peoplePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

## CNContactPickerDelegate methods

```
func contactPicker(picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelectContacts contacts: [CNContact]){
        contacts.forEach { contact in
            for number in contact.phoneNumbers {
                let phoneNumber = number.value as! CNPhoneNumber
                print("number is = \(phoneNumber)")
            }
        }
    }

func contactPickerDidCancel(picker: CNContactPickerViewController) {
    print("Cancel Contact Picker")
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Methods of `CNContactPickerDelegate` is changed in Swift 3 like below.

```
func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contacts: [CNContact]) {
    //your code
}

func contactPickerDidCancel(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController) {
    //your code
}
```

For other methods of `CNContactPickerDelegate` check [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/contactsui/CNContactPickerDelegate/).

Comment: Thanks. Now, I only need to retrieve the data I want and finally this will work again...

Comment: Welcome mate :)